# How distribute the result of an Ajax request into multiple divs?

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

Let me further explain what I try to achieve.

I'm iterating over a table in the PHP file I'm requesting the data from.
For every row in this table, I print a div with some contents inside. Or more specifically a bootstrap card. (see code at the very bottom)

First of all, I request the data

```html
<div id="result"></div>

<script>
function load_data()
{
    $.ajax({
        url:"_cards.php",
        method:"POST",
        success:function(data)
        {
            $('#result').html(data);
        }
    });
}

load_data()
</script>
```

This would squeeze the response in a single div (id=result).
But what I'm looking for is a way to print every single bootstrap card in its own div. Order each card from left to right, row by row. Or having the cards in a bootstrap grid would be fine too. I just don't know how I can split the response up and dynamically distribute it in separate divs.

Here the PHP file I'm requesting the data from:

```php
<?php
include '../../_Database.php';
$db = Database::getInstance();

$result = mysqli_query($db->link, "SELECT * FROM `Workorder` WHERE isLocked = 0");
{
    $wo = $row['idWorkOrder'];
    $a  = $row['Article_idArticle'];
    $oQ = $row['orderQuantity'];
    $cQ = $row['currentQuantity'];

    echo '<div class="card" style="width: 100%; text-align: center;">';
    echo '  <div class="card-body">';
    echo '      <b>' . $wo . '</b></p>';
    echo '      <h5 class="card-title" style="zoom:0.8">' . $db->getArticleString($a) . '</h5>';
    echo '      <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">'. $db->getFirstNameFromWorkorder($row['idWorkOrder']) . $db->getLastNameFromWorkorder($row['idWorkOrder']).'</h6>';
    echo        $cQ . ' / ' . $oQ ;
    echo '  </div>';
    echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

Each iteration over the table would print such a card. In my current setup they're printed and stacked on top of each other. I want them printed left to right row by row, or something similar.
How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that they are stacking is that they are not in any for of row/column grid.

You can fix this by enclosing the loop in a `<div class="row">` and each card in a `<div class="col-md-3">` (for example, resulting in 4 columns)

This way, you'll see all of the cards in a grid rather than stacked.

Example:

```php
echo '<div class="row">';

while (mysqli_fetch_row()) { // looping over rows
    $wo = $row['idWorkOrder'];
    $a  = $row['Article_idArticle'];
    $oQ = $row['orderQuantity'];
    $cQ = $row['currentQuantity'];

    echo '<div class="col-md-3">';
    echo '  <div class="card" style="width: 100%; text-align: center;">';
    echo '    <div class="card-body">';
    echo '        <b>' . $wo . '</b></p>';
    echo '        <h5 class="card-title" style="zoom:0.8">' . $db->getArticleString($a) . '</h5>';
    echo '        <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">'. $db->getFirstNameFromWorkorder($row['idWorkOrder']) . $db->getLastNameFromWorkorder($row['idWorkOrder']).'</h6>';
    echo          $cQ . ' / ' . $oQ ;
    echo '    </div>';
    echo '  </div>';
    echo '</div>';
}
echo '</div>';
?>
```

Comment: You're my hero. My lack of understandig how the bootstrap grid works left me clueless. I thought I'd need to declare another class="row" to actually move down one line. But the col-md-3 was enough to actually do that. 12 / 3 = 4 divs in one row. THANK YOU